# Proving that $C=\{A \cup N : A \in \mathcal{A}, N \in \mathcal{N}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having trouble proving this part (for a bigger homework problem).

I have to prove that the set

$$C=\{A \cup N : A \in \mathcal{A}, N \in \mathcal{N}\}$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra where $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mathcal{N}$ is the collection of all null sets with respect to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mu$.

I am stuck in the part of proving closure under complements. I already completed closure under unions.

Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $N \in \mathcal{N}$. Then $(A \cup N)^C = A^C \cap N^C$. But I don't know how to proceed. I thought the complement of a null set would have measure equal to that of the set $X$ (Assuming it is part of the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$).

Is it better to prove also closure under intersections and then use that and closure under unions to prove closure under complements?

Comment: Intersections and unions together do not imply complements..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is meant by null set, I assume the following
$$\mathcal N := \{N\subseteq X \mid \exists F\in\mathcal A, N\subseteq F, \mu (F) = 0\}. $$
Take $U\in\mathcal C$, then $U = A\cup N$ and pick $F \in \mathcal A$ with $N \subseteq F$ and $\mu(F)=0$ and note that
$$U^c = (A\cup N)^c = (A\cup F)^c \cup (F\setminus U) $$
Convince yourself, this satisfies the criteria of $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that is what I mean by null set.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing here is the definition of a null set. When you say that $N$ is a null set you mean that that exits $B \in \mathcal A$ such that $B \subseteq N$ and $B$ has measure $0$. Now $A^{c}\cap N^{c}=(A^{c}\cap B^{c}) \cup  C$ where $C=A^{c}\cap N^{c} \setminus A^{c}\cap B^{c}$ Now check that $ A^{c}\cap N^{c} \setminus A^{c}\cap B^{c}$ is a null set. (It is actually contained in $B$).